# Create object of class within a class but not using the name

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am sorry if the heading is misleading, I can't think of a better heading.

so I have two classes like this :

```
class ClassA{
   getObject(){
      return new this(with some parameters)
   }
}
class ClassB extends classA{

}
let a = new ClassB();
a.getObject();
```

I know I can always return new `ClassB()` with some parameters. But `ClassA` is extended by some hundred classes and it will be a lot of change in every class.
So Is there a way to return object of self class in `getObject` method of `ClassA`?

Comment: `getObject` is static ? or is in an instance method ? Because `new this` will not work in an instance method, might work in a static method.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir `getObject` is not static it is an instance method and it should return an instance of `ClassB`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use polymorphic `this` to return an instance of the same type as the current class:

```
class ClassA {
    getObject(): this {
        // not really type safe, not really recomnded 
        return new (this as any).constructor()
    }
}
class ClassB extends ClassA {

}
let a = new ClassB();
let b = a.getObject(); // ClassB
console.log(a.getObject() instanceof ClassB); // true
```

You can also infer the type of `this` using a type parameter and use that as the return type:

```
class ClassA {
    getObject<T>(this:T) : T {
        // not really type safe
        return new (this as any).constructor()
    }
}
class ClassB extends ClassA {

}
let a = new ClassB();
let b = a.getObject(); // ClassB
console.log(a.getObject() instanceof ClassB); // true
```

Comment: `this.contructor()` is already working. I just wanna ask that will it be equal to `new ClassB()` ?

Comment: like `this.constructor()' is same as `new ClassB()` ?

Comment: @MamoonAhmed yes, that will be whatever constructor created the object

Comment: Sorry but this is not working. Sorry for accepting it as an answer earlier.

Comment: `this.constructor()` is not making a new object. here is some code demo
this is inside `getObject()` method
`let obj = this.constructor();`
`console.log(obj.prop == this.prop)`
the expression writes true to the the console. It shouldnt write true because `this.prop` is an `HTMLElement`

Comment: @MamoonAhmed sorry, my bad .. forgot the `new`, should work now

Comment: using new gives me this error in typescript `Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature`

Comment: Checked again. `new (this as any).constructor()` is working but `new (this as ClassA).constructor()` is giving me error.